# How can I ensure that the stats are the result of human action and not automation?

Tags: tracking

Note: I'm talking about Amplitude because it's what I use, but it's probably the same with any stats tool.

Amplitude, because of its very nature, is insufficiently secured.

Stats are the value you get out of Amplitude.

A user makes an action, this action is sent to Amplitude and has an impact on the stats.

This means that anyone can sabotage my stats. Even if the routes are secured, even if all the logic concerning the events is in the backend and invisible to the user, it is possible for anyone to sabotage my stats.

If I put no security on my amplitude route, anyone can access it as easily as they want.

If I put an authentication on my amplitude route, anyone can create an account and then do all sorts of actions in an automated way and industrial quantity and sabotage my stats.

If I put all the logic in the backend, anyone can do the same as said previously, but since they don't know if and how I record events, they will do it blindly. They will still be able to do it, anyway.

And the more I lower the risk by adding security, the less I am able to track some events. If only an action dealing with the backend in an authenticated way can be recorded, then I cannot track the click on "register instead" on the sign in page, for example.

I feel like I've got to accept that my stats cannot be entirely secured. Is it true? Am I thinking the whole thing incorrectly? How should I deal with that? Open unsecured routes so I can track some events, given that the attacker will find the way to sabotage me anyway?

Comment: What would/could an attacker gain by fouling your stats? Would you start making costly investments if your stats tell you you get 10M requests/second, but your server tells you it is operating at a load of 0.01 (or similarly, your cloud provider indicated you are well within the limits of your current subscription)?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau idk it might be a competitor who decides to attack me in whatever way they can. The stats I am using are useful for understanding the user experience.

Comment: The general approach for dealing with this is to try to identify "inauthentic" patterns or excessive traffic and exclude IPs that are producing bad data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the internet, you cannot trust client-generated data. But then again, you might be overestimating the value of 100% accurate statistics.

What you can do is to make it more difficult to fake incoming data. For example, if you measure interactions on your backend, you can use techniques like CSRF tokens to make sure that interactions come from visitors (or bots) that actually visited your site. Slightly nonstandard configurations might cut down on non-targeted spam. For example, back in the Google Universal Analytics days, site identifiers like UA-XXXXX-1 would see way more referrer spam than UA-XXXXX-2.

Regardless of what initial filtering methods you use, you'll have to view your collected data with healthy scepticism. Data-driven does not mean data-only. Techniques like anomaly detection or rate limits might be useful in excluding faked interactions, but they might also remove very interesting real interactions. In the end, data itself does not tell you anything, but you might be able to *analyze* it in ways that are useful for your purposes. Performing useful analyses a difficult problem, and there cannot be a one-size-fits-all solution.

For example, consider you're performing an A/B test. An attacker generates lots of interactions. But since they can't pick whether they are part of class A or B, this is just noise. It doesn't invalidate the test, it just makes the test less sensitive.

As another example, you might be analyzing conversion rates across multiple steps of a funnel. Attackers are unlikely to fake data that proceeds through the entire funnel, so that data on later steps is likely to be reliable. However, data on landing pages might underestimate the true conversion rate, making them look worse than they are.

Similarly, it might be possible to filter interactions to only look at ”accounts that have spent at least $1”, “users that have completed a goal” or “accounts that are at least 2 days old”. This is not perfect, and it might not fit all your analysis purposes, but you can zero in on cohorts or demographics that you expect to be representative of your actual audience.

Even very minor checks might make targeted attacks economically infeasible, and entirely prevent untargeted attacks. If someone has the criminal energy to confuse your statistics by generating fake interactions, they probably have more efficient ways to hurt your business.